# PDO select multiple table with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I have 4 identical table with same row names with diffrend values.
I have send $_GET['urun_barkod'] code from another page so im trying to show matched row on 2nd page with detailed row information.

```
$barko=$_GET['barkod'];
$urunsor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kanyon UNION ALL SELECT * FROM zorlu UNION ALL SELECT * FROM 
tesvikiye UNION ALL SELECT * FROM citys where urun_barkod=:barkod");
$urunsor->execute(array(
    'barkod' => $barko
));
$uruncek=$urunsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But i cant get the result correctly.
Just wanted to show matched barkod row on my 2nd page with details.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: out of curiosity, what's the use case for having 4 identical tables?

Comment: i assigned each table for each store they include id, name, price, quantity, color rows.

Comment: That should all be in one table, with an additional column to identify the store.

Comment: And will also mean in turn you won't have to run more complex queries to return simple data

Comment: Actually my first attempt was one table but then i split them into 4 table. I know but im still learning so i'd like to learn every way to do this.

Comment: it shouldnt be so hard to marge 4 table and match one row with get value. I was using this method but have no idea how to do with multiple table so as soon as i know the code must be correct but why i cant get the correct result idk.

Comment: "I'd like to learn every way to do this." Learning is worthwhile, but in this case you are trying to learn to do something incorrectly. The reason you're finding this difficult is because it's not meant to be done this way.

Comment: Yes, fix your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that your where Clause, works only on the last Select

So You need to en capsule the union and then do your where clause

Like

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM kanyon UNION ALL SELECT * FROM zorlu UNION ALL SELECT * FROM 
tesvikiye UNION ALL SELECT * FROM citys) a
 where urun_barkod=1
```

The problem is you gather all the data from all Tables and union them, and finally then you remove all the unnecessary rows  , which makes no sense at all, because it takes time and resources.

So do better this

```
SELECT * FROM kanyon  where urun_barkod=1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM zorlu  where urun_barkod=1 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tesvikiye  where urun_barkod=1
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM citys where urun_barkod=1;
```

Which  only unions the actual wanted rows.

In my opinion i would also add a column in the selects to identify the tables, but that me.

Answer (score 0):

If the id's are identical, please try:

```
"
SELECT     *
FROM    ((kanyon INNER JOIN zorlu ON kanyon.id = zorlu.id)
                INNER JOIN tesvikiye ON kanyon.id = tesvikiye.id)
        INNER JOIN citys ON kanyon.id = citys.id        

where urun_barkod=:barkod
"
```

Comment: unfortunetly id's are not identical. thats why im actually trying to match their urun_barkod numbers. btw "urun_barkod" rows are VARCHAR maybe thats the reason that i cant success with my code?

Comment: Have you tried to use simple `Union`, without `ALL`? It can be usefull in your case. It used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set.

Comment: I did try use UNION actually notting changed. The only diffrence is put ALL next to UNION right? (btw i changed all the urun_barkod rows VARCHAR to INT) well this is so confusing it should work but hmm..